# Website Address Bar graphic

Tags: favicon

How do you get the graphic that is next to the address bar show up?
I have a very simple site, and I want to make a custom image, and have it show up when a user is on my site.
Thanks

Comment: also, can i download a site's image like i can if the graphic was in a page?

Comment: http://www.google.com/q=favicon ... voting to close as this is not programming related.

Comment: I disagree. It directly relates to building a website.  Would you close a question about how to build sprites for use with css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a 16x16 favicon.ico file in your websites root directory.

You can produce one in any number of graphic editing programs (including paint).

http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html

Comment: New versions of IE use a 32x32 icon if available.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on wikipedia, which seems to well describe what you are asking:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Personally, I find [the explanation on h2g2](http://h2g2.com/A14116943) is usually better written than that on Wikipedia, on almost any subject.

Answer (score 1):

What your after is a favicon.ico file, check out the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) article for more details.

There are also [a number](http://www.favicon.cc) of [online generators](http://genfavicon.com/) out there. See [Google](http://www.google.com/search?&q=favicon+generator) for more =)

favicon.ico files are also used by some browsers when a user bookmarks your site.

Answer (score 1):

Make a square image and edit it the way that you want. Make sure that you don't add any small details. Next, go to http://www.favicon.cc.com/ . This site will convert your image to a supported .ico format. Rename the file favicon.ico and put it in the root directory of your site. You should have a favicon in your browser now.

Answer (score 1):

This icon, is a favicon, and you have to upload a file to your site if you want it. But if you want to make your favicon work in all browsers properly, you will have to add more than 10 files in the correct sizes and formats.

My friend and I have created an App just for this! you can find it in [faviconit.com](http://faviconit.com)

We did this, so people don´t have to create all these images and the correct tags by hand, create all of them used to annoy me a lot!

The file generated comes with a small explanation on what to do with the files. We will make it better, but it's a start.

Hope it helps!